# Jquery Onclick .post returns // Uncaught SyntaxError: '' string literal contains an unescaped line break

Tags: php, jquery

I have a simple click/post in jquery :

```
$(".login").click(function(){
  var txt = "1";
    $.post("content.php", {choiceregister: txt}, function(result){    
    $(".this").html(result);
    });
});
```

The result is added to .this

In content.php I have a simple div, the div is multiline.

```
echo '
<form method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                E-mail:
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="email">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Password:
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="password" name="password">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="submit" value="Login">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>';
```

Not sure why I Get this Uncaught SyntaxError: '' string literal contains an unescaped line break. Should be simple enough. If you have any idea it would be appreciated.

Comment: What `simple div`, I see a `<form>`? Side note: save yourself now! ... avoid using tables as form layouts!!

Comment: Replace all blank spaces may be.

Comment: @PaulT. You are right about the div ... it's form my bad. And for table you are also right. It's would be better all in div. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here you receive HTML content response, you didn't declare on your post method,

Make your request as like below

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "content.php",
      data: myKeyVals,
      dataType: "html", //here we mention the response data type
      success: function(result) { 
           $("replace your element selector").html(result); 
      }
});
```

hope it will working for you.